# How to build a table with angularjs and track which row user selected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am reading User data from a database and generating a row per user in a simple . For each user, the row has two columns - firstName and Actions. Actions is a dropdown list with options - Edit, Delete. here is the html.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="l in list">
        <td>{{l.name}}</td>
        <td>
            <select ng-model="selected_action" ng-change="action()">
                <option ng-repeat="a in actions" value="{{a}}"> {{a}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the action() function I tried to simply have an alert like this: alert("selected action: "+$scope.selected_action); but angularjs displays "selected action: undefined". Interestingly, I noticed that $scope does not even have selected_action as a variable when debugging via Chrome. My goal here is simple to take the user to a new form when from a table user selects edit/delete for a user. Can someone please guide me here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<select ng-model=selected_action ng-options="a for a in actions">
  <option value="">-- choose an action --</option>
</select>
```

Take a look at the angularjs docu for select at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Comment: @chapstick I've created a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/TdDnf1HplfZv3reGhzMY?p=preview. Is this what you want? Take a look at the angular js docu for ng-change http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChange. "Evaluate given expression when user changes the input. The expression is not evaluated when the value change is coming from the model." Thats why you get undefined. You need to pass the model as a param to the action function.

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the passing of selected_action in action().